# Ignore error rows when inserting into an table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Says I have this t-sql command :

```
Insert into x(a,b) select a,b from y
```

While x contains 10 records, two of them will generate errors when inserted into y, like `string should be truncated` or `numeric overflow`. Now what I want is when the command is executed, only 8 records will be inserted into y, meaning that all error records will be ignored.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

cannot understand, why such requirement is there. solution is there, but still not satisfied with requirement or say not able to digest such scenario.

you can loop through each record one by one and if no error then insert.
try this

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare  @Id            Int
        ,@Total         Int
        ,@Loop          Int
        ,@a             Varchar(5)
        ,@b             Numeric(3,1)

If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#x') Is Not Null
Begin
    Drop Table #x;
End

If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#y') Is Not Null
Begin
    Drop Table #y;
End

Create Table #x
(
     Id         Int Identity(1,1) Primary Key
    ,a          Varchar(5)
    ,b          Numeric(3,1)
)

Create Table #y
(
     Id         Int Identity(1,1) Primary Key
    ,a          Varchar(10)
    ,b          Numeric(5,2)
)

Insert Into #y(a,b)
Values 
 ('abcdef',200)
,('abc',12)
,('abfdef',260)
,('34c',16)
,('abwe',18)
,('asdc',29)
,('3fgc',17)
,('a45we',88)
,('a3d7',49)
,('a367',48)

Select   @Total = Count(*)
        ,@Id = 0
        ,@Loop = 0
From    #y With (Nolock)

While (@Loop < @Total)
Begin
    Select  Top 1
             @Id = y.Id
            ,@a = Substring(y.a,0,5)
            ,@b = Cast(y.b As Numeric(3,1))
    From    #y As y With (Nolock)
    Where   y.Id > @Id
    Order By y.Id Asc

    If @@Error <> 0 Goto NextLevel

    Insert Into #x
    Select   @a
            ,@b

    Goto NextLevel

    NextLevel:
    Select  @Loop = @Loop + 1
End

Select  *
From    #x With (Nolock)
```